# Bootstrap bugs on codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

perhaps the video will easily explain the problem. here's the link to my [video](http://youtu.be/EWkFxpCwQ0k) .

here's the `view` code

```
<div class="col-sm-4">


<?php echo form_open('user/updateuser');
  ?>



<legend>Update User</legend> 


<div class="form-group">
    <label for="id">ID</label>
    <input name="id" type="text" class="form-control" id="id" placeholder="Input id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" disabled>
     <?php echo form_error('id'); ?>     
  </div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input name="username" type="input" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Input Username" value="<?php echo $username;?>">
     <?php echo form_error('username'); ?>   
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Old Password:</label>
    <input name="old_password" type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Input Old Password"" value ="<?php set_value('old_password');?>">
    <?php echo form_error('old_password')?>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">New Password:</label>
    <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Input Password" ">
    <?php echo form_error('password')?>
  </div>


  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">New Password Confirmation:</label>
    <input name="password_conf" type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Input Password Confirmation">
    <?php echo form_error('password_conf')?>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email address</label>
        <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
        <?php echo form_error('email')?>
  </div>      

  <div class="form-group" align="center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button> 

<button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger">Clear</button>
      </div>
 </div>  
  <?php 
    echo form_close(); 
  ?>
```

and here's the controller `user/updateuser`

```
function index()
{
    //This method will have the credentials validation    
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">', '</div>');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('old_password', 'Old Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_password');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|matches[password_conf]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password_conf', 'Password Confirmation', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

    if($this->isloggedin('logged_in'))
    {                           
        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {                       
            $data = array(
                'sess_username' =>  $this->isloggedin('logged_in'),
                'id'            =>  $this->input->post('id'),
                'username'      =>  $this->input->post('username'),
                'email'         =>  $this->input->post('email')

            );                                  

            $this->load->view('header');
            $this->load->view('main/menu_super_admin',$data);
            $this->load->view('user/modifuser');                
            $this->load->view('footer');
        }
        else
        {           
            $query = $this->m_user->updateuser($this->input->post('id'),$this->input->post('username'),md5($this->input->post('password')),$this->input->post('email'));

            if($query)
            {
                echo "<script>window.onload = function() { return alert(\" Update User Success ! \"); }</script>";
            }
            else 
            {
                return false;
            }

        redirect('user/user', 'refresh');
          }
    }
    else
    {
        redirect('login', 'refresh');
    }
}
```

the problem is, i want to make the disabled input stay disabled and the values remains the same,

is there any mistakes on my code ?

Answer (score 1):

Disabled inputs are not posted to the server: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#disabled

> ... [a disabled input] cannot receive user input nor will its value be submitted with the form.

I suggest getting the ID from the session and not relying on the posted information in any way (This is a security concern because posted information can be manipulated by the end user).  You already check to see if the user is logged in.  Just get the ID from the the session while you're at it.

Session ID can be retrieved like so:

```
$data = array(
    'sess_username' =>  $this->isloggedin('logged_in'),
    'id'            =>  $this->session->userdata('session_id'),
    'username'      =>  $this->input->post('username'),
    'email'         =>  $this->input->post('email')
);
```

You may also need to load the library first

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

I also suggest using `sess_use_database` [as mentioned in the docs](https://ellislab.com/codeIgniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html) for added session security.